# How to insert class parameters into SQL(nvarchar(50) field) and use in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, class, parameters

I will insert any data from `cls1` into SQL Server (`Nvarchar(50)` column). The code shown here is sample from my project

Please help me

Thanks

```
class Cls1
{
    public static string projectid;
    public static string projectname;
}

using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdInsert.CommandText = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO total(projectid)" +
                                           "values(@projectid)");

    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectid", (ClsPQR1. projectid));
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hey dud here nobody is God here nobody can understand your question by your code. You have not write a single meaningful word in your question. I can understand that you are new to Stack Overflow. But Please ask meaningful questions.

Comment: The code looks about right, is it causing an error?  and if so what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the command:

```
using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdInsert.CommandText = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO total(projectid)" +
                                           "values(@projectid)");

    cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectid", (ClsPQR1. projectid));
    cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

More for [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: no problem for cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery(); into main project is exists.